# Using AudioToolbox for short sound effects volume control not working on iPad/iPod touch models

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, audiotoolbox

Everything works fine on the iPhone Models, using the volume buttons on the phone raise and lower the games audio. On iPad and iPod touch models volume buttons don't effect the games sound effects.

Here is the code I am using to play these short sounds.

```
-(IBAction) playClickSound {
  CFURLRef mySoundUrl = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), CFSTR("click"), CFSTR("caf"), NULL);
  SystemSoundID mySound;
  AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(mySoundUrl, & mySound);
  CFRelease(mySoundUrl);
  // Plays the sound.
  AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(mySound);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could the constant "kAudioServicesPropertyIsUISound" affect the level?  It is supposed to determine whether or not the user's settings affect playback.